# Firefox starts up in Japanese from GUI, in English from command line

Tags: centos, firefox, locale

I've just installed CentOS 8 (build 1905).  I use the system in English (with Hebrew as a secondary relevant language) - not in Japanese. After some initial activity (which doesn't involve playing with locales), I've somehow found myself in the following situation:

- If I start Firefox through the desktop UI, it comes up with Japanese text on the menus and the error pages.
- If I start Firefox from a shell (in an xterm), it starts up with English UI.

Why could this be happening and how can I fix it?

**Additional information:**

Contents of `/etc/locale.conf`:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Installed Firefox package:

```
#  rpm -qa | grep -i firefox
firefox-68.2.0-2.el8_0.x86_64
```

Comment: What is the output of `rpm -qa | grep -i firefox` ? Please add said output to the question.

Comment: @schaiba: Done.

Comment: Go to `about:preferences` and check the language settings, alternatives and preferred language.

Comment: @schaiba: Nothing is selected in the Language settings. The alternatives are `[en]` and `[en_US]` in that  order.